# Delimit output created using a grep command

Tags: shell, grep, git-bash, delimited

I want to run a line of code to create a Text to columns output on a file which is comma delimited.

I have created a file which results in the output been created in the format comma delimited. So all the data is in column A separated by a `,`.
The file is `apilist.xls`
I want to add a line of code that will take the data here and separate out the data in to the columns, similar to the excel command text to columns.

I have tried:

```sh
$ cat apilist.xls | tr "\\t" "," > apilist.csv
```

This gives the message:

> bash: $: command not found

It creates the `apilist.csv` file but there is no data in this.

Any suggestions on how to progress this?

```sh
$ cat apilist.xls | tr "\\t" "," > apilist.csv
```

Delimited output - move the data from one column to be separated into multiple columns.

Comment: if your input file is already comma separated, why you `tr "\t" ","`?  which role `grep` is gonna play in your question? also, paste some sample data as input, and expected output from the input.

Comment: It seems that you run the following command `$` instead of `cat ...`

Comment: `$` is a generic shell prompt, not a command you'd actually type... If you see an answer with something like `$ foo`, it means `foo` is being run in an interactive shell session.

Comment: Input - Illiquid Flag,Exception Sub Type,Primary ID,ID_GLOBAL,ID_SEDOL1,ID_UNIQUE,SECURITY_TYP,FIGI LAST_UPDATE_DT,FIGI PX_LAST,,SEDOL LAST_UPDATE_DT,SEDOL PX_LAST,,UNIQUE LAST_UPDATE_DT,UNIQUE PX_LAST,,PRICING_SOURCE,CRNCY,QUOTED_CRNCY,FIGI SEDOL PRICE CHECK,FIGI BBU PRICE CHECK,SEDOL BBU PRICE CHECK,,PrimaryIdentifier,SUBSCRIBER,PRICE_DATE,SERVICE_PRICE,PRICING_SOURCE,PRICE_CRNCY in column A

Comment: Illiquid Flag Exception Sub Type Primary ID ID_GLOBAL ID_SEDOL1 ID_UNIQUE SECURITY_TYP FIGI LAST_UPDATE_DT FIGI PX_LAST  SEDOL LAST_UPDATE_DT SEDOL PX_LAST  UNIQUE LAST_UPDATE_DT UNIQUE PX_LAST  PRICING_SOURCE CRNCY QUOTED_CRNCY FIGI SEDOL PRICE CHECK FIGI BBU PRICE CHECK SEDOL BBU PRICE CHECK  PrimaryIdentifier CL_SUBSCRIBER PRICE_DATE SERVICE_PRICE PRICING_SOURCE PRICE_CRNCY
- output delimited by the comma

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert your .xls file to .csv before you're able to work on it. Here are a number of methods to convert the file: https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/methods-convert-xlsx-format-files-csv-linux-cli/

You could then use awk to create columns between the data where it is separated by a comma. This is assuming that you have three columns separated by a comma - you would need to edit the below command to meet your needs:

```
awk -F ',' '{printf("%s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3)}' input_file
```

Comment: When I actually changed my input file from .xls to .csv the delimited action happened automatically, I didnt require nay further code to initiate this. I still need to test further but for now I think this is closed/answered. Thanks to all for their input.

Comment: The CLI can read the .csv without any further applications as opposed to the .xls file. Sounds good that it is now working.